# a javascript function does not work on the console

Tags: javascript, console

I am following a tutorial  to learn javascript and I am trying to run my function  in the console to see the output like this
[image]
and this is my code

```
var output = [];
var count = 1;

function fizzBuzz() {

    output.Push(count);
    count++;

    console.log(output);
}
```

but instead, it shows like this in the console
[image]
so what is the reason for this? Could you help me please
also I am a very beginner

Comment: Watch the `()` behind in the tutorial.

Comment: The method is `.push`. `.Push` does not exist. You also forgot to invoke the function.

Answer (score 0):

To call a function you have to end with (), otherwise it just shows you what the actual function is as it would a variable, so fizzbuzz gives you the content of the function, fizzbuzz() executes the function.
As a side note, the p in push should be lowercase.